# why after login send me when i click on browser back button to login page in angular 10?

Tags: browser, safari, back-button, angular10, node-ios-device

If login we redirect to our home page called bookings. I used the following angular code for that:

```
// if login we store IsLogin

if (localStorage.getItem('IsLogin') != null) {
     window.history.forward();
}
```

This is working fine in Chrome, Firefox in desktop but not in mobile devices safari browser (iOS devices and Android).

If user logged then user can't go to login page using browser back button, how to restricts this (during mobile devices)?

Comment: A few questions. Firstly I'm very curious where `IsLogin` is set from, and how login validation is coordinated between the client and server. Secondly, I am ***very*** confused why you are sending the browser *forward* once the user has logged in; this can only be possible if the browser has navigated back a page to begin with (and the Forward action is enabled), and in normal browsing circumstances this is almost never the case. IMHO, I am not at all surprised this doesn't work on mobile.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "If user logged", but regardless of whether I was logged out or logged in, I'm not sure why I'd want to click the browser Back button to go to the login page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.